# Why does an empty struct in C# consume memory

Tags: c#, .net, generics, memory-management, value-type

I always understood structs (value types) contain exactly the number of bytes as defined in the fields of the structure... however, I did some tests and there seems to be an exception for the empty structs:

```
public class EmptyStructTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FindMemoryLoad<FooStruct>((id) => new FooStruct());
        FindMemoryLoad<Bar<FooStruct>>((id) => new Bar<FooStruct>(id));
        FindMemoryLoad<Bar<int>>((id) => new Bar<int>(id));
        FindMemoryLoad<int>((id) => id);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void FindMemoryLoad<T>(Func<int, T> creator) where T : new()
    {
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        long start = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        T[] ids = new T[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; ++i)
        {
            ids[i] = creator(i);
        }

        long end = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", ((double)end-start) / 10000.0, ids.Length);
    }

    public struct FooStruct { }

    public struct Bar<T> where T : struct
    {
        public Bar(int id) { value = id; thing = default(T); }

        public int value;
        public T thing;
    }
}
```

If you run the program, you'll find that en FooStruct which has obviously 0 bytes of data will consume 1 byte of memory. The reason this is a problem for me is that I want `Bar<FooStruct>` to consume exactly 4 bytes (because I'm going to allocate it a lot).

Why does it have this behavior and is there a way to fix this (e.g. is there a special thing that consumes 0 bytes-- I'm not looking for a redesign)?

Comment: P.S.: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=0)] gives the same result.

Comment: Is GC.GetTotalMemory accurate?   If so I wasted money on a memory profiler.

Comment: Why don't you just skip Bar and have FooStruct include the public int value;?

Comment: @Blam, no it isn't accurate: ["Retrieves the number of bytes currently **thought** to be allocated"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx).

Comment: Pff yes and true, but in these cases it's pretty damn accurate... If you don't believe me feel free to check using a profiler (put it on the heap by creating a class first, otherwise it won't show up!).

Comment: Allowing values to have 0 bytes creates the kind of singularity that swallows black holes.  With the array being a clear victim, all of its elements would have the same address.  Test this not by using a corner case, test this for the kind of structure you are concerned about.

Comment: @HansPassant Ehm yes- so what? Surely it doesn't create 'black holes'! Arrays in f.ex. Pascal store the length in a variable and then the elements - the only reason here can be the implementation of an array. I also cannot see a boundary condition when using generics, value types that have the same address, etc, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Summary**: An empty struct in .NET consumes 1 byte. You can think of this as `packing`, since the unnamed byte is only accessible via unsafe code.

**More information**: if you do all your pointer arithmetic according to values reported by .NET, things work out consistently.

The following example illustrates using adjacent 0-byte structures on the stack, but these observations obviously apply to arrays of 0-byte structures as well.

```
struct z { };

unsafe static void foo()
{
    var z3 = default(z);
    bool _;
    long cb_pack, Δz, cb_raw;
    var z2 = default(z);    // (reversed since stack offsets are negative)
    var z1 = default(z);
    var z0 = default(z);

    // stack packing differs between x64 and x86
    cb_pack = (long)&z1 - (long)&z0; // --> 1 on x64, 4 on x86

    // pointer arithmetic should give packing in units of z-size
    Δz = &z1 - &z0; // --> 1 on x64, 4 on x86

    // if one asks for the value of such a 'z-size'...
    cb_raw = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(z));     // --> 1

    // ...then the claim holds up:
    _ = cb_pack == Δz * cb_raw;     // --> true

    // so you cannot rely on special knowledge that cb_pack==0 or cb_raw==0
    _ = &z0 /* + 0 */ == &z1;   // --> false
    _ = &z0 /* + 0 + 0 */ == &z2;   // --> false

    // instead, the pointer arithmetic you meant was:
    _ = &z0 + cb_pack == &z1;   // --> true
    _ = &z0 + cb_pack + cb_pack == &z2; // --> true

    // array indexing also works using reported values
    _ = &(&z0)[Δz] == &z1;  // --> true

    // the default structure 'by-value' comparison asserts that
    // all z instances are (globally) equivalent...
    _ = EqualityComparer<z>.Default.Equals(z0, z1); // --> true

    // ...even when there are intervening non-z objects which
    // would prevent putative 'overlaying' of 0-sized structs:
    _ = EqualityComparer<z>.Default.Equals(z0, z3); // --> true

    // same result with boxing/unboxing
    _ = Object.Equals(z0, z3);  // -> true

    // this one is never true for boxed value types
    _ = Object.ReferenceEquals(z0, z0); // -> false
}
```

As I mentioned in a comment, @supercat got it right when he noted, "There probably wouldn't have been any problem with designing .NET to allow for zero-length structures from the beginning, but there could be some things that would break if it were to start doing so now."

**EDIT:** If you need to programmatically distinguish between 0-byte vs. 1-byte value types, you can use the following:

```
public static bool IsZeroSizeStruct(Type t)
{
    return t.IsValueType && !t.IsPrimitive && 
           t.GetFields((BindingFlags)0x34).All(fi => IsZeroSizeStruct(fi.FieldType));
}
```

Note that this correctly identifies arbitrarily nested structs where the total size would be zero.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct z { };
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct zz { public z _z, __z, ___z; };
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct zzz { private zz _zz; };
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct zzzi { public zzz _zzz; int _i; };

/// ...

c = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(z));      // 1
c = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(zz));     // 3
c = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(zzz));    // 3
c = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(zzzi));   // 8

_ = IsZeroSizeStruct(typeof(z));    // true
_ = IsZeroSizeStruct(typeof(zz));   // true 
_ = IsZeroSizeStruct(typeof(zzz));  // true
_ = IsZeroSizeStruct(typeof(zzzi)); // false
```

[edit: see comment] <strike>What's strange here is that, when nesting 0-byte structs, the single-byte minimum can accumulate (i.e. into 3 bytes for 'zz' and 'zzz') but then suddenly all of that chaff disappears as soon as a single "substantial" field is included.</strike>

Comment: What do you mean, "chaff disappears"?  `zzzi` is 8 bytes, only 4 of which is the "substantial field".  The padding didn't disappear, it got padded *more* to properly align the `int`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, you are correct. I think I might have mistakenly thought `int _i` was a `long` here, therefore occupying the full 8 bytes reported by `sizeof zzzi`. That would have been mysterious. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 10):

It's the same reason zero-sized objects aren't allowed in C (or C++): pointer arithmetic in terms of number of elements.

C# supports pointer subtraction in unsafe blocks, defined thus:

> Given two expressions, `P` and `Q`, of a pointer type `T*`, the expression `P – Q` computes the difference between the addresses given by `P` and `Q` and then divides that difference by `sizeof(T)`.

Since division by zero is not possible, this implies that `sizeof(T) > 0` for all `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Null / Empty value for a struct in .Net 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819677/null-empty-value-for-a-struct-in-net-1-x)

This solution mentions not having any overhead, which I believe is what you are looking for.

Furthermore, Stroustrup talks about why structs aren't empty in C++, now the language is different, but the principle is the same: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty

Comment: In C++, every object is assumed to have a distinct identity encapsulated by its address.  Thus, every object must make the address that is assigned to it unavailable to any other object.  The simplest way to do that is to make each object take a minimum of one addressable unit.  I don't think such a thing should be necessary in .NET, since I'm unaware of any paradigm of comparing byrefs for equality.

Comment: @supercat I thought about that too... but perhaps it does make sense -- after all, how are you supposed to write iterators and so on in unsafe code if the size is really 0.

Comment: @kirk sorry, you're solution is just plain wrong in this scenario. Jon is right though, you should read his comment and his question again.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: I'm unware of any argument that would compel me to impose a minimum size of struct in the design of .net.  Since there's no kind of "primitive only" generic type parameter, I can't see how code could try to loop through a fixed array without knowing the underlying type.  Further, even one were writing code to call a method repeatedly with byrefs to consecutive elements in a fixed array, every array in .net has a item-based length which is not dependent upon its physical allocation. `for(i=0, ptr=array_data; i<array_length; ptr+=array_item_size, i++) do_something(ref *ptr);`

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: ...should work just fine even if `array_item_size` were zero.  The `ptr` value wouldn't go anyplace, but so what?  Perhaps one could say that an ability to compare pointers of some type would imply the type must have non-zero size, but I'm not sure when one would really need to compare pointers to things of unknown or generic type.

Comment: @supercat The so what is evident when you use the pointer in unsafe code - but you're right in the fact that that's an implementation detail. Thinking about it that is however probably the reason - after all, it's easier to implement the .NET engine if you assume you can optimize array iterations in a certain way. I'm perfectly fine with that conclusion, for me it's perfectly valid... my current workaround then becomes the only workaround (e.g.: make a different 'Bar' struct without the empty member).

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: I find it hard to imagine situations where having a zero-sized struct would actually break things in any framework where pointers are not regarded as identifiers.  Algorithms in some unmanaged code might have trouble with zero-sized structs, but I would expect such code to be used only with data types for which was particularly designed.  If an algorithm won't work with zero-byte structures, don't code it to use them.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: Even if one implements something like a copy operation `endptr = src + count; while(src < endptr) *dest++ = *src++;`, and uses the pointer to track the end condition, a zero size wouldn't cause any trouble.  Regardless of `count`, `endptr` would equal `src`, and thus the loop would instantly exit.

Comment: @supercat I agree with you all along the way, but apparently it uses 1 byte for some reason. As I see it, the best candidate so far for that reason is the implementation of `ldlen` that might use pointer arithmetic under the hood. If that was broken, it would give serious trouble... But I'm just guessing here. Still, you are right, I also don't know of any 'real' reason, just implementation details.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: I would guess that .NET does it because C++ does it, and C++ has to do it because pointers are expected to behave as references.  There probably wouldn't have been any problem with designing .NET to allow for zero-length structures from the beginning, but there could be some things that would break if it were to start doing so now.

Comment: kirk, the first link you posted is not relevant; it concerns how to work with semantically 'empty' values of (presumably non-zero-sized) structs, as opposed to the unmanaged size of structures which contain no instance fields; @supercat: yes, I believe your last comment nailed it. Quite unfortunate.